# About the usage of some words in literature

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

How to understand **lay some way out**. 
The following is a piece of excerpt from *Treasure Island*

> The Hispaniola **lay some way out**, and we went under the figureheads and
>   around the sterns of many other ships and their cables sometimes
>   grated underneath our keel, and sometimes swung above us.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The thing is about the meaning not grammar structure.

Comment: The verb form _**lay**_ here is the simple past of the English verb to lie. What English language dictionary do you use in your study of English? What does that English language dictionary tell you about the English verb _**"to lie"**_? The phrase **_some way out_** is an adverbial that modifies the verb, and means _moderately distant_.

Comment: Yes, exactly! What does your English language dictionary tell you about the **meanings** of the verb _**"to lie"**_? What English language dictionary do you use?

Comment: @P.E.Dant To lie is polysemy. I’m not sure which meaning is used here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant why can I not search the phrase some way out in dictionary. I’m using a lot of different dictionaries.

Comment: _**"Lay some way out"**_ is not a "set phrase" in English. You are unlikely to find it defined as a phrase in any dictionary. What you should do instead is to learn about the many meanings of the English verb _**"to lie"**_. Yes, _to lie_ has many meanings. Which one might apply to a sailing ship like the _Hispañola_? Can a sailing ship tell an untruth?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Well in that sentence *lie* isn't a regular verb, so it can't be that.

Comment: @userr2684291 how to understand out here

Comment: I imagine, but I wouldn't bet my bottom dollar on this, that they're on a small vessel and they're approaching the Hispaniola that's moored in the harbor, away (*way out*) from the narrator.

Comment: @userr2684291  Your comment is indecipherable. _To lie_ is an irregular verb in _every_ sentence!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'll clarify. *To lie*, when it means "to deliberately say something that's not true" is a regular verb: *he lied*, *he had lied*, so it makes no sense to talk about that meaning when trying to find the true meaning of *lay* in that sentence, the form which belongs to the irregular verb *to lie*.

Comment: @userr2684291 Ah, so! That never crossed my mind. This makes the intended meaning even easier to deduce, although perhaps not to a new learner of English. My intention in commentary here is to convince the OP to consider _lie_ and _some way out_ as discrete entities, rather than as some kind of set phrase. Your helpful comment advances that effort, although it is rather cryptic in its short form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this:

> [**Usage note**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lay?s=t) 
>   *Lay* and *lie* are often confused. *Lay* is most commonly a transitive verb and takes an object. Its forms are regular. If “place”
>   or “put” can be substituted in a sentence, a form of *lay* is called
>   for: *Lay* the folders on the desk. The mason is *laying* brick. She
>   *laid* the baby in the crib. *Lay* also has many intransitive senses, among them “to *lay* eggs” ( The hens have stopped *laying*), and it
>   forms many phrasal verbs, such as *lay* off “to dismiss (from
>   employment)” or “to stop annoying or teasing” and *lay* over “to make
>   a stop.”
>
> *Lie*, with the overall senses “to be in a horizontal position, recline” and “to rest, remain, be situated, etc.,” is intransitive and
>   takes no object. Its forms are irregular; its past tense form is
>   identical with the present tense or infinitive form of *lay*: *Lie*
>   down, children. Abandoned cars were *lying* along the road. The dog
>   *lay* in the shade and watched the kittens play. The folders have *lain* on the desk since yesterday.
>
> In all but the most careful, formal speech, forms of *lay* are
>   commonly heard in senses normally associated with *lie*. In edited
>   written English such uses of *lay* are rare and are usually considered
>   nonstandard: *Lay* down, children. The dog *laid* in the shade.
>   Abandoned cars were *laying* along the road. The folders have *laid*
>   on the desk since yesterday.

I wanted to highlight all the confusion that exists between definitions of *lay* and definitions of *lie*.  *Lay* can be a tense of *lie* but *lay* can also be its own verb.  In this case, *lay* is being used as *a transitive verb and takes an object* and the object is the phrase *out*.  One could also describe that phrase as *out [there]* where *[there]* is understood.  A [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lay?s=t) of *lay* is:

> to place, set, or locate: 
>   *The scene is laid in France.*

It is also important to note that *lay* is a common word in nautical usage and the definition of *lay* for nautical usage is also relevant

> *Nautical.* to move or turn (a sailing vessel) into a certain position
>   or direction.

In this case, the Hispaniola is both sitting *some way out* and also there is a need to *lay a course* to the Hispaniola.  The use of the word *lay* is intended to invoke both connotations at once.  The word *lay* is also intended to invoke common language of seamen, so as these nautical words come up in the narration the reader has a feeling of being there, in the boat, with sailors speaking language of the sea.